# iPhone Core Data - How to save an entity's new value?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have an Entity, say, Person, which has a attribute Name.

I create it via Context and obtain an Person's instance. Now I give

person.name = @"Jack";

then How do I update this in the persistant store? You may say using [Context save], but if I call that method, will context save everything that came out from it?

For example, if I do

person1.name = @"Jack1";
person2.name = @"Jack2";

I just want to update person1.name, but not person2.name, how do I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you change the value of `person2.name` if you don't wish to save it? Remember, you are talking about an object graph here i.e. a collection of objects in memory whose attributes you are altering. The cortex has to save the entire graph because that is the only way to maintain the graph's integrity. You might want to look at the undo functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get to pick and choose which objects get saved and which don't. Objects in the managed object context that have been modified will be updated when you save the context, and saving a context is the only way to save changes to objects in that context.

If you want to work with person2 but might not want to commit whatever changes you make, you can create a separate managed object context. This works well if person2 is a new object and therefore not connected to any other objects in the store, but it can get a little complicated if person2 might already exist in the first context. Core Data doesn't sync changes between contexts by itself: read [Communicating Changes Between Contexts](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdChangeManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001201-SW5) for more about how to handle this.

Comment: I mark this answer to be the one because I think caleb gives more info. Asad, u r right too, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

why dont you save context as soon as you set value for the person.name Jack ....? & continue working with Jack2

Comment: If the person quits the app, the App Delegate probably has a [context save] in it already. I'm with Asad on this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One of my points is about the performance. If I call [context save], will it scan all associated objects and save them all? I guess that's low performance when I want to save only one obj, right? also, do you mean, I give a "save" each time when I just want to save one obj? thanks